# How to insert multiline text in a svg element

Tags: javascript, svg, text

As a primer in svg and javascript I've been trying for a while to make this code work with no avail.

My problem is that I'm not able to take the text from a text element (`class="texts"`) and put it into another one (`MySpeechBoxText1`) maintaining it's multiline formatting.

Here is my code:

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" 
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" 
  version="1.1" 
  width="594mm" height="420mm" id="svg58064" 
  viewBox="0 0 2245.0393 1587.4016">
 
     <style>
        .bar {
            fill: #a9a9a9;
            opacity: 0.6;
         }  
        </style>

 <g class="miogruppo">
      <rect class="bar" x="50" y="60" width="80" height="120"/>
      <text class="texts" x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" display='none'>
     <tspan x="20" dy="1.2em">test 1</tspan>
        <tspan x="20" dy="1.2em">test 1</tspan>
   </text>
    </g>
 
 <g class="miogruppo">
   <rect class="bar" x="180" y="80" width="80" height="170"/> 
   <text class="texts" x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" display='none'>
     <tspan x="20" dy="1.2em">test 2</tspan>
        <tspan x="20" dy="1.2em">test 2</tspan>
   </text>
 </g>

    <g id="group1" display='none'>
  <title>Tester 2</title>
  <path id="test1" 
        d="M15,0 H150 V150 H15 L15,90 L0,90 L15,75 Z15 " 
      style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;
      stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:0.5;fill:#ffffff" 
      inkscape:connector-curvature="0"/>
      <text id="MySpeechBoxText1" x="60" y="60" > </text>
        </g>
    
      <script><![CDATA[
        var bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bar');
     var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('texts');
     var mySpeechBox = document.getElementById("group1");
        var MySpeechBoxText1 = document.getElementById("MySpeechBoxText1");

    for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
      bars[i].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverEffect);
      bars[i].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutEffect);
   bars[i].addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveEffect(i));
    }

 for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      texts[i].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverEffect);
      texts[i].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutEffect);
   texts[i].addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveEffect(i));
    }
 
    function mouseOverEffect() {
   mySpeechBox.style.display='block';
    }

    function mouseOutEffect() {
   mySpeechBox.style.display='none';
    }
 
 function mousemoveEffect(a) {
  return function() {
  
   var myX = +bars[a].getAttribute("x");
   var myY = +bars[a].getAttribute("y");
      var myWidth = +bars[a].getAttribute("width");
      var myHeight = +bars[a].getAttribute("height");
   var MySumX =myX + myWidth/2;
   var MySumY =myY + myHeight/2 - 90;
  
   mySpeechBox.setAttribute("transform", 'translate(' + MySumX + ',' + MySumY + ')');
   
   //MySpeechBoxText1.style.whiteSpace = "pre";
   MySpeechBoxText1.textContent = texts[a].textContent; //here the text should be multiline
  }
    }
     ]]></script>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Please create the working fiddle, the code posted have lot of errors.

Comment: Just copy my code into a text file, save it a "xxx.svg" and open it with your default browser (in my case Chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `textContent`, use `innerHTML`.

```js
const text1 = document.querySelector('.text1');
const text2 = document.querySelector('.text2');

text2.innerHTML = text1.innerHTML;
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
      .small { font: italic 13px sans-serif; }
      .heavy { font: bold 30px sans-serif; }
  
      /* Note that the color of the text is set with the    *
       * fill property, the color property is for HTML only */
      .Rrrrr { font: italic 40px serif; fill: red; }
    </style>
  
    <text class="text1" x="0" y="5" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="blue" >
      <tspan x="20" dy="1.2em">test 1</tspan>
      <tspan x="20" dy="1.2em">test 1</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="25" y="25" class="text2"></text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Tons of thanks. Your tip is so simple and effective!